# How to sort the fields in CreateView of Django?

Tags: django

I just learned django last January and I'm currently working on website to store and show lyrics. My problem is that in createview the fields are not sorted.

Here is my models.py:

```
class Singer(models.Model):
song_singer = models.CharField(max_length=200)

def __str__(self):
    return self.song_singer

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('singer_author')

class Lyrics(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
singer = models.ForeignKey(Singer, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
type = models.ForeignKey(Type, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
lyrics = models.TextField()
```

Views.py:

```
class AddSongView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
model = Lyrics
fields = ['title', 'singer', 'type', 'lyrics']
```

[Screenshot in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fue16.jpg)

As you can see in the attached screenshot, the choices from singer field is not sorted. How to sort those choices? Thank you!

Comment: Please share your `Singer` model.

Comment: `class Singer(models.Model):
    song_singer = models.CharField(max_length=200)

Here is my singer models. Thanks!

Comment: please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by defining a default [**`ordering=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering) on your `Singer` model, this will then order the items by name if you do not specify another ordering:

```
class Singer(models.Model):
    # …
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['song_singer']
```

Comment: Wow, I was not expecting that somebody will reply to my question so quickly your answer solved my problem. Thank you so much! BTW, this is my first post in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Best to use a ModelForm here. This also gives you the chance to modify your form even more:

```
from django import forms

class SongForm(forms.ModelForm):
    singer = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Singer.objects.all().order_by('song_singer'))
    
    class Meta:
        model = Lyrics
        fields = ['title', 'singer', 'type', 'lyrics']

class AddSongView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = SongForm
```

Comment: I'll try this one. Thank you so much!